# Open XML Altchunk Html with base64 images Embedded

Tags: c#, html, base64, openxml-sdk

**In short:** I would like to create a word document from htmlstring and the html contains embedded base64 images.

**My problem:**
I have managed to create the word document with the use of Altchunk, but when I open the document the place where the image should be doesn't display the image but shows the message:

The linked image cannot be displayed. The file may have been moved,renamed, or deleted. Verify that the link points to the correct file and location.

**My code:**

```
string base64Image = @"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAATsAAABbCAYAAAAMXyIpAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAAEnQAABJ0Ad5mH3gAACoVSURBVHhe7Z13dF3Ftcbff6+/lZW38l54byV5AUKHQEILEBISSIBQAqG3QIBQQugdGzDYgHHvuGFsY1uWewUbN1nuVbZkSZZkq1rV6r3cs9/5je6I0dG50tW1bMu68601S1dXc+ZM2fubvffsc/QPYmFhYREFsGRnYWERFbBkZ2FhERWwZGdhYREViA6ya6oTKUoT2TNHnK8GuD/nilQVBf9oYWERDejbZJexUZy40eIseV2cOU+IM/a34gy9TGTpmyL5+4OVLCwsogF9muycTRPEmXiLOB+dJ84HZ4jzzn+L8/b3RGY8KJK2LljLwsIiGtC3yW7DKHFGXq0Irl1xCVC5shYWFlGDvk12e+eJM+m2jmQ34iqXCEcGa1lYWEQD+nbM7vBmcWY91pHsPrlInJXvBitZWFhEA04NsqvMESlOFGmqcc01J/hlGChKFZn/fEeyG3C6OLHPijTWdq89CwuLUxa9l+ycgEhDhUjmanHi3xNn3WsiWWtEmuuDFcIA6SWuBef0/9/2ZNfvNHG+uE+kPFck0BKsbGFh0ZfRO8muuU6kLF2c5LniLLpHAuN+KIHxPxLn66ddKy/bJaimYMUuADHGjRJn4NntyY7y2U0ueW5z6zQGK1tYWPRl9D6yc1xLq/Sga80NkMCE0yUw9N8k8Ok/tpYxp4mkxIrUlQQrh4GdM8UZfmVHsht9rciemFZX1sLCos+j95FdbZE4eydJYOT3JDDkX1yS+6dvyQ7im3apOLnxwcpdw9m/SFlxHchu2BUq4VgaqoM1LSws+jJ6H9m1uK5n9npxYm6QwLD/+JboVHGJb/h3xPnmBZGCncELukBGnDizH+9Idh9fIM7Cl1wrsTxY0cLCoi+jd8bsqvPF2TdVAhPPbu/G6jLpPHG2DRGpKQxe0AkKkkRW9O9IdjxRMe1et42jwYoWFhZ9Gb2T7ALNIlW5EvjqydbDCS/ZUWJvESdtcfCwopP0kYojIhvHdiS7934gzrjrRcpy7ImshUUUoHeSHWhpFCd/hwTm3ui6s//ekexG/Zc4yx52STGv9VAjFOoqRHbNEqff99uTHeknwy53XeYd9pDCwiIK0HvJDmsNwtv7mQRmXt2R7Ib8swQmny/OlkEuWVUGr/EBr3c6sEKcwRd1JLxB54gkLROpLQ1WtrCw6KvoxWQXhOvOqjSUcT/qSHjDvyOBLy4TJ2OFSH1Z8AIPSE7msTHXZXX6/097svvwTJGtk0Uq84OVLSws+ip6P9mBnDjXZX2kI9lpwltyv4jr8qpYnx/yEsSZ8aA47/6gPdkN+HHrM7IlGcGKFhYWfRWnBtm5VpuTPFsCE8+SwNB/bU92Q/5JAiO+K87WwSLlh4MXeFB0sPUFnu//X3uye++H6kUBcsS+yNPCoq/jhJGdE2hxi2t5RfrgPY+PxfWTwOjTWuN1JuG5xZl6sTgJU0RaGoIXGKjIE9k0XpwPzmxPdjwzO4HHxra7lewLASws+jJOGNk1VR6R+qIUCTR2880lGhBlxWEJxPy+9ekKD9mRj+cseUCc7LjgBQZqSkQSFogz8Kz2ZMebiweeow4wpNmHJC0sLPoMTgjZtTRUytHd0+VwzCOSu/JNqc6Ml5b6iuBfu4HmenUYEZh1nX86yoQzxFnzskhtcevBhAaPhB2KF2fQue3JjtLvNJHdMa6rXBWsbGFh0RdxQsgOcsta+IwkDj1Pksdcrj6X7JgqtXm7u0d6wdc+OVs+lsDnl3QkO+J50y4TZ88EkUbjmdeWJpFi1w0e8YuOJ7JukbgxIuWuq2thYdFncXzJziUnyCx/3ceSOvE6SRxyTls5OOl6ZeWVH1giDUfTXfe22vVuw3ySoXCvOKuelcAoH3d2xHclMOMakbwt7QnPdWWdKXe0nsB6yW55P5H8xGBFCwuLvojjSnZOc4NUHYqTjJl3tSM6s6RO+JUcWfWe1GRvleaaYnGwwsJB6nxxcGd9DivU6ezKJ0WKEtxOBAm0tkycuc/4urIS+4xIpkuOFhYWfRbHlexa6solZ8kLkjz2Sl+ioyQNPV8OjPq5HJx8gxSsHyx1BWGmgZCOkjg9+CooD+HpdJS9E9UroxQaqsRZ+6k4Qy/tQHbO5Ntbn6SwsLDosziuZBdoqpOy/QtUjC5l/DW+ZKdL0rALlKur4nnbp0hd/v7OrTwstpIDLoG94hLef7YnO13m3iRO+tLW+jz/unOGOCOv6Uh27neye3ZrPQsLiz6J4+vGBlpUyknVofVSGD9SncYmj75MEoee60t4FKy89Gm3Su6KN6T8wGKpL0lrTVfxA3G+vC2ue3qjejFAB7Ib/f3Wd98V7WtNLUnfIM7433Uku4/PFyd+vHoW18LCom/i+B5QGGiqzJfy5GWSu/xVSf/i9iDpnedLeJSk4RdKxsy7pSBuiFSmr5HGitzWpGQvmmpa3303/Ur/d9+RbLzlo9ZnZ0uzxJlyZ0ey++AMkTWfunU6eaGAhYXFKY0TRnYAsmquKZGyxAWSOe8J17W9WpGaH9mZBXIs3jJOGstzlJXX7tSWdJTGSmXB8U95OpCdW5wvf6mer1V5enOeaP1Xiry8k3/E89G5rf+PIn6cfZGnhUUfxgklOwWXnIjlkW5Crh3Wmx/BmYV4HjG/w3MfldJ9MdJU7XlDsdsm7mxgyQO+ZKfSUb50Ca0sQ73bTlYPEuH/TyQtbX1UrDClleggTgsLiz6JE092QTgtja3xvMNxUrhxuKRPu00OjLzEl+worae2l0ra57dI3qr+UpG8XLm2bWhwrbuEKa47e0VHshv/Y3FWPydSkekW95qjh0VcK1G9x46DC/6doiU6C4s+jZNGdhqtVt4hKU9aJHlf95O0abd06doqKy/mESmMGybVmZukubbE5apmkdI09TJPdVhBOsro70tgzg3ibP5QhP9I5hJiW96dhYVFVOGkk52JuqIDUrxtomTGPqaSjbHm/MhOl5RxV0n2ouekNGGOys9Tj54V7hZn0d0SmPpT9Q48JznGdVELgnewsLCIVvQo2TmuK9jiWmrNrmsYaG5wra3uW1GO61LWFSRK/poPJXXib5RrmzSsE9Ibeq5KV8lZ/qpUZayTlqoj6kWezs6R6rVQFhYWFqDHyA6ia6w5Kjl7l0jm9jlSlL5JasvyIiA8RyUTN9eWSnX2Vte1fVuRni/R6QLhuaRIPI/4n7LwcFn9UlUsLCyiEj1GdgGXoCqOHJD9ywfJtpnPyK65r0jC4vckde1Yyd61QIrS4qWyMFWa6ioVMXYJx1EvByCpuCxxobLcUsZe1WluXtqUG6Vo89iILEoLC4u+jR4ju5ameslL/Ep2zH5BNoz7U2sZf5dsmvyw+i5h0buSvGqYHNr8hRxx6xVnbJGK/BSpqyxUbi/kFgpYeTXZ21wiGydZC56S1AnXqnQUk+g41MhZ+qKqZ2FhYeFFj5Fdc0O1pK4bL1umPfEt2fmUuPF3y7YZT8vehf0kZe0Yydo1X4oOxrnElyw1R7OkvqrYbaumg3XG77xYgEfPjqz5QL1JJXnMFd9adZ/frA4qeNOKhYWFhRc9Q3auVdZQUyq7570hGyfe70tyoUrchHtk89RHZc/8tyTlm9GSs2exlGbvkbqKfOXytqjDjsZ2rm9zXamUJy+V7IXPKMIjXsdjZfXFqcEaFhYWFu3RI2TX3FgnZbn7XavucZfA7upAaF2VONfd3fjZvRI/8QHl9mId7pzzkiR99alk7ZwnR7N2KYuvDS7xqfy8skwpC+bn1R7Z635tDyQsLCz80SNkx+EEllhuwlJJXTtO9i54R7ZO/6sir0jIj1gf5IfFt/3Lv8nu2Ndl/7KBcnDDRMl23d7ijM1SXZIpTbXl0lxzVBrUm1GMtxJbWFhYeNAjZNeaX9egrK/KglQpTt/sEt8yObR5uiSvHqHic9tn/V02T/mzP7mFUbS7u2PW85Kw5H1JWTNaMrfNlsLUDSpeGNYJr4WFRdSixw4ovMDaa3CtrsrCNJeQ4pQ7enDdOElY/K5KS+GQYpNLfhs/u8+X3MIp8ZMfUuktkKwlOwsLi85w3MjODxw04O7ihh7e+qUkrvhExeY2T31Mxeo43MCCC9f1jZ/0oOxd1F+a6iL4t4wWIeE4jjQ1NanS0tKifrc4+dDrUldXJ7W1tarwme/0GrFeeu10aW5utmvo4oSSnbtcKoWER8nIreMEl9hbSeZO1/KLlaSVg5W72xrr8yc4sxAXTI//XKWqWPQcUJDk5GTZt2+fZGVlSU2Nnd/eANaBNVm4cKHMnDlTFT7zHX+D6PLy8trWjpKYmCiZmZmKFKMdYZHdnDmx7crixUt7ZPJwPXF3ibnVVxZKdfEhKctJkIKU9ZK5PUYOrBouexa87ZLaU77u7s6Yl1wXeb20BHPrEhOTOvSV7yy6h7KyMvnrX/8qd999t3z66aeyf3+Y/wTJ4rigvr5eli9fLq+//rpak5tuukl+97vfqXLnnXfKjBkzpKKiQgoKCtR6PfbYY6oe5ZFHHpEvv/xS8vPzg61FL8IiuwEDBrUrw4ePkqqq1tPPgGupNTXWS11NpTTW10pzU6P6LlJg+WGp4e6W5yWqw468fSskY/MXKhVl97w31eNom6Y8IvuWvK8SkXUC8oYNGzv0le8suoeioiK58sor5fTTT1ekt2nTpuBfLE40SktL5euvv5ZHH31ULrnkErUmZrnoootk1KhRaoM6fPiwPPnkk+3qXXjhhTJo0CD1t2jHMZNdfW21FOWkS+quDZKesFmyknfLkUNJUpidJsW5GVJyJFPKCnOloiRfKkuLpLq8RGoqS6W+pkqRI0TZ4rpNgU5iQ+TPNdaUueSXJPlJq9UpbOq6cerpC2XVBa872WSnYyppaWmydetW2bVrlxQWFir34lSCJbveAWQJGXrqqafkvPPOayMws3RFdhdccIG8++67kp5u3wB0zGRXWpAtO1fHyuxPn1cldsSrsnDcO7J00gfy1bTB8s2skRK/eKps/3qO7F67UPZtXC4Htn0jhxK3SW76finIOihH87Ok8miB1FaVK/JsqKtRRZFhQ71LiA3KYmxphhSbFTGS6sLzuCZONtkFAgHlTgwYMECuu+46ueeee2TZsmWnXLzEkl3vwNGjR2XOnDly8cUXy5lnntlGYGeddZb89Kc/lZ///Ody7bXXysSJE6W8vNySXRc4ZrIrzjssW1fOaiO72UNekDmUoS9KzNCXJGbYyzJ3+CuKBGNHvibzRr4u80a9IfNHvykLxrwlC8a+7ZJjP1k2eaB8PWOIrJ0zWuIWTJTNS6crgtwfv1xSdqyTQ/u3uhbjAWVFlhbmKOuw2SVBE72F7J5//nnlPtxyyy2W7CwiBgcLI0eObEd0lN/85jcyevRoWblypaxZs0YOHTokjY2Nluy6wDGTHe7qpqXTviW7CAvECCnOcwlREaFLgotcElw6cYAsmzJQVnz+sSLDVV8Ol29mj5Rda+ZLQWaK6oNGbyG7v/3tb3L++efLH/7wB0t2FhGD09R+/fq1ERflnHPOkSeeeEJycnKU64q8cYCBy2vJrnMcM9kdyUiU9fMm+BLY8SxrXAswK3mX6oOGJbuewYkgO+KbKGllZaVSWn7ye2f5YOSLMZdm4btw4L22qzhqJP3zAmtL3897Lffne9xP0kb4TH0TxOtee+21NuKiIFcvvvhisMa36EmyM+dK9y+ceTbHq0u480zd43UPjWMmu9y0/bI+dpzMHfGK67K+pFxYP3Lq6bIudry6t4meIDsmH8FhEquqqhR5UVjwhoaGkBML0fH3kpISefbZZ5VQkiJAHhSKQpuUUAsa6X27AvdDmKqrq9va5DP3CoVIyI7+6TFSmA8v6Av3xz3bu3evrF27VhYtWiSxsbHq57p161ReGIc69NkEc4C7Rl82bNjQVqjPiaUf9JxmZ2fLzp07212XkpKi+uIFibq5ubnd7p8JxqkPqfT96DfpHxAn7e/Zs0dWrVol8+fPl6VLl8o333yj+kj6COtDPe5PSEQTFwW5euaZZ1RbxcXFSt7oM+M8FrJjrpA92k1ISFBj1f3DXY6Pj1cpSFiU9M+URz4zJ945poQ6oOM7iDQpKUk2btyo6na2lsgTf9u9e3eHexw5ciRYq3Mce8wuN0N2r10gq2YOk+VTP5LFE96Vha4LquJxbsElnTfqdeWexo6gvKrcVWJ5MUNfdMmR0hrn8yO1UCVu4STXjW3/SqdjJTsWAHJBOXAhWGCEkLjItm3blIIgDJARws4CICQUBA5hQ0lIE+D07Le//a1MmDBBJXnyN5QcIjGhSZKF5+/e++7YsUNSU1OVEtA3P8Hxgv5QD+ElyRSBQvFok8Jn+qNJj/omukt2zAXX0CZJyHz2Win0B8FHicgFe+ihh+T666+Xyy+/XCknP2+44Qa1UZAXxlzTf02aKDb5ZOSN/fGPf2wrb731lqxfv17V8UIryNixY+XPf/5zu+tIx4BwNKjL/KJM1O9u/zSYS9bygw8+kAcffLDtfg888IDExMQoAhk3bpzKhfvVr36lDhlonwMtTl0ZIxbdV199JcOGDZN77723jbgoyNUdd9whn3/+uSLhBQsWyIEDB9R8R0p2euyQ2RdffKEIFq9E9++aa66RG2+8Uf7yl7/ImDFjlPxAsloWWX8I8bnnnms3xxTkjba9QF82b96svKA//elPqi5rCcF75xRwD/SBvpnt33XXXbJixYpgrc5xzGTH6Whjg2um11RKVVmRlBbkSGFOuuRlJElWyi7J2LdFEreskj3rF8mOVTGyZdl02egSFeRILG7R+P7qwIJC3M6P2PzKluUz1EGFiWMlO5Rx3rx5atFuu+02tcgsNuWyyy5TBw4I0yeffKKEFgWELFgISOmll15Swvmzn/1MzjjjDCWYCDGCzXW0i5CawLpg0d9//32lEFiD+r7cE8JkUf/+978rQYS8uiI8+qTHwnW33nprm+BS+Pzwww+rlAWImPomukt2JLwSW2KML7zwghoP1qwG/aXfkAhJsKRLnHvuuepUkeC7LvzOnKGsxKUWL16s2kH4KXPnzlVKd/bZZ7eVm2++WZ1G+oFxQfQQF/czrxs6dGgbAdA295k0aZJSHk46u9s/De4J4T/99NOKIPX9GDNkxlpeccUVqv2f/OQnbW3zmbb5GwQAsXINMTpNXBTkivY4oaUfyMpnn32mCDZSsmNDgFzZEH7xi18o65F76P7xk7HTZ2SbMUyfPl2NE0C0bBz33Xdf23h14SBF1zPB5o0uMGbGSF0OXtgIvXMKMDCGDBmi9Em3zdjoS6jNzotjJjsTJBOTHkKqCGkjDbXVKtm4uuKoVJUWScXRAikvPqJIqiTvsDpZzT+cLNmpe+Vw0g45uGejJG9fI/s3rZS9G5bIzjXzFalhxa2dM0ZWThssyyZ/6FqP/ZU1Sd6eiWMhO3bHESNGKGW69NJLFSkgrL/85S/VDn/11Ve3CRjfsRuxy2EFsjiQH0SH8CEUCBoLAmH9/ve/VySGoqNkGgjn5MmT5f7775errrpKCTfCxqKTHc99uZ7v6RN9g1C9ZGICa2379u3Sv39/Rc5cR79ph7a1IvMTIkWxVq9e3c59CJfssEgRNBSftiEe5hC3QhMoLp3O7Kc/CKhWxM4K84zyQShYUADrGjI169Ee32E9eC1UrluyZInql64PWVx44YWKOCEIwLUQHRZTd/oHic6aNUtZKRqM2490IA3WgvYhD7MtXegXmywWHWTnV8dbkI1jybNjbbAOkV2uC9U3XZg/yJB+jh8/Xt2TzYx22Fjpj1mfDR559QJyfPPNN9vVhfgef/xxFQLwhnsYn3dsOn6J+xsOepTsIoF6PZRLkI31rnVYWyW1lWWuhViskpBLC3PbCDE3bZ9LiNslI2GLIsWCrFRFqCYiJTsWCusAgoGg2C0wqRGiKVOmqF0MZSB/DlMeQcQ6YmdCsVEq3Jpp06ap3QdyYyeELCETLBranzp1qnLjNCAR3CKEHLLAGoAMqcc9dXssKETH4kLCb7zxhlpgr0Cww0IIEB3kiaAjlK+88opSIFxqSEc/dkT/UMD33ntPkb1uLxyyY6flXvSfNrBIuA9uuGkp4u4Qt6T/CLMWVG350geu9SoJBcGGSJlbrGc2FlxAruN6XY+xeO+LAmJ5Dxw4UG1Auq5e3y1btqjxMg4+s3mZRIfSsyasJZYxa05/IC1dhw0DVxXF1YQXiuzMwjoybr1G3Iu2sIxYezYQ3HW+81p2FMZgWunIViRkh7zgZrLG3jmlT1xLH9kskWf9Nwr9Yt55Phf5pyC7v/71r9vVY4Nj/U1wXw7uvC46hblm82W9NZhT+q/1U9dlfpAHYqDh4KSTXU8iUrKDgCAxFhCrCncR5cfawVLSheAsdSGvDz/8UDIyMpR1A1AcrC3cNUgLgWZxiMGgdLoNcxGJD0GgLDpuIEqH+6nrooj8jjJBVigeygY5sBtry0QDMqAeVihjIakZsiaOCOno9iAPLBusRITr448/bov7gK7IDsUmrkSfUQiUgaA51q0JCIdgt/cJABQJdwjLiE0FcoY09Sah61FoG9InVsqcEBtCwU0LBAuVcZqxIdaFWCdzwGai6/LZfHyKNWQNzDr0lTYZHxsE8oA7xsbFvJgKB0mTC8fcg67IjrVj3O+8844KXTBvbASEFdg82Xj15gvR0w/zesbN+NnwKGxUEBZr212yQxYgKEjTvAckQp/oG33EcsbqZVMz6zF25gS9YK0hNS+B0TZzqPUEELrhO+TUrEuBLJlPyFu7stQnXmf2k3lgE4MYvXoQCj1Cdq07JMp5Yot2bzQiITsmFEFGqBDkt99+2/eUzgQC7RdX4HeuRQA02XndHC8OHjzo9nFDl7E4FPejjz5qsyyw+EwB5t64bLjECAI7Mrun6Z6agHS5N3E9hN60ijojO9aaONjgwYMVEUGqKConit5ANOOmD9QzLSJ+5xraRbGZM05amSvuaxIZLjfkAGHjpnJvL3nSHnFRnjjQrizESPumgtIH2mfD0uvHYRBhCX1PrBsUbvjw4e3ccWSNexMgJySg24T4COYTOuDeociOdqn78ssvS1xcnBozCg1RQKbME5uiBnNJ//1ST3ANuV4X1jLUfTsjOzYs2jLbZ46IW7LB6Fw+5oH1RRbMdaTgOXCoAJnhbWDde+uwmSHfGrTrzR/UhbXkgI9NSG++WG64zJCwrgfREuPmUM+U3c7QI2R36NBh9d2JLrx9xUR3yQ5hR+jZ6dkliJGxyF6l9QKh9hId8JIdsSIIyEvKJiAPBKUzogMoL/ErTRzEO/Rpoh4HQo3lgPuFMKE8fv0EjIF70zfurUkCdEZ2CBfuPZsDRIeicxrG7mq2ASAyLC6v8OPaEBDHGuHe9JG+cF/6Tf91XSw91gWFQqkhZk5DTYWmfdYPhdaCj0IRUzUVRCsS9VAk1ooTUpNcIVHGrIlOj4mfkDfWN7FXXV+TGGTVGeloUmTc3JcxUxg/8sY6mGvF/UjlCJVnp6+nUDcSsiOdBtfZbB/5YX2RHb02/GR98Sa0/On6eEJYocgndXAracNsEwuRE1wN1pLNyayjC22zUUPE2kiARBmXucFRB6vTT+5CoUfI7uDBtA51TkThFU4mukt2Wkhw41AW3AN2dJQwEiAYJtkh3ChBZ2QXLmgDN5F+opwEg1E8AFEQ1CWgj1L5xT26Az+yY2woAFYw7SP0WK6QBcSAQnhBnzi51gJK8bo+JhgjhG4eKCD8xLdQTAgdBYDkmVt9EETBLaYO1h1Exuk4oQmzDnOHdYy1y3iwHnDj9N91HfpsEp0G19AHwhQQvXkdJ6KaIP1IR5MUius3V3443knFHI5xcGa2T+ySDRqZMkGfsV5xZ5ExXR/SwZVG7rkGT8FcPwqWIt9rYKUhO2YdsyBbOnQBkHNv6CIcr8mLqCY7DdwIFBgrADeQADFmd3dJ6niTHbEZjt5ZdHZLXDCAZUhiJoF3BAHznuP+cJXKCy/Z4XZBEMQfsWoYG6RA3BLSQtH8QLyO2JQWUAq7Pm6Ntm5M0A4HDQS+dX3IDuXFmtPWBtYdJAAJ6nqmUrNZ4XZhIWoFwUJEkc1NIFT/GDMHRKEKrps3tsiGSVggEtIJheNNdmzs3gMFTkNDpXKQpoQbTx90fcIEfKfjZsgksmm2qcMCWj+IFWuLm3kkPkj8TrfLT9pkfXCjsSix6vQBCtegp2xo2tUNB5bsXDBpxFIIUjOpWE3sPhAVi4cJjktB3AiB1jEuv52/u2SH8uLGEJdg16cv3M9bIBwORlBGCMAkO9onOMwujXIjsH5kEi5MsqMtrC1cD8iCOeJ73BeCzAh5qPv4KasmSb/+MReQNGSt6yPg3BN3GMsJsJvPnj1bHWjoetqiZa44LGD99N8oWAuQhOnaUxelMuthsUEWWCyhimkt6gKhkJR7KpEdFizrYbZvypUXtEFbtKnrM69Y0Do2jLXMIRnrockJax79Ys05lMPS09ezthwQYS0TO+U7yAz54j1+6AREqetTsOJfffXVTsM0frBk5wKyIRudRWDymWwWCuLDemDi2c1JMyBtAyuDRSVOYVpPTHx3yI76uF24BygngooLgPXmV8xYiCmUKP/MmTOVac99uX9PkR07KK4fhwK0TUHZEXhcGhQ81Ph6gux0IS6kyQ7Fxsqgb2b8iMLjTRAzhGB+r60LE1jKHJSY9SItjJPxRhvZ8ZkTWOQYsK5YYlh85toQG8RYYB2JwfIdOsZhD5spJ9He+CGuLPrjXUs2OcIG3YUlOxdYaJjLxAY4rNA5bSwGCwb5sVOx67O4CBMBeqwLrDyN7pIdOxNxEwgOsx5y5V5YZ37FFJ4TRXYQLGRPu4wbF4TYILs1feb0mticH44X2elYK4c0pmJTIGaKN26E9WHmOAJLdj1Pdqwp+ZdY2WZsD51iDfEUdAoJYyEsQqYBLivWmq5PIeUF48K7lhgdPLXTXfQI2WEZQXgnuuTltX8AOFKyAyiazlXC0uLUjKAqMRqsLpJTyQljYVksSIkdhl1Jm/Dhkh3KypzRNvEpXAEIBaKFQLk31olZ+A73oCs3tqfJDoHVlhwnpWTD80JJ5gECJi7GPPmluGD1oRymoGIpEyfz6x8Ki8Vm5mppN5ZgNLmCJpgrrEuzfawDYpdco79jE6EfpLeY8HNjcVOxYlHM7hTWgs2rL5MdpERqCX3Q9b1uLGDzY41NUkRuyRvkpyZBPpMryLoydzx9Y+bSQZAkc3vXkrYJJ3UXPUJ2vQXHQnZeEPiE/FgIDitQQsxwyAtrBoGCdIg3kH8FwiU7bcGQ48TiQpoc99MOMTDvSRigjVAHFATcCbyzm0LC7J5YnKaL3R2YZEfBJSHplx2bOYE0OJXVc8AOTF+8wWIEksC9boeCNUh9v/55D1ootM99CDNgfZtgPVA+82SUvurgty64sDyZQNjBhN8BBXWxDLEiu1M4pWXdTiWy8zugwNJFzvzgl+PoPaAA6AzhBPOAiGvM3yl4IngkeCbIDhu2mdaD92ASK4XNiM3Fu5bhwJJdN8GioJCY1hCL6R6FS3a0AXGwsOxaBGf9ngc00RnZ0R4HKNra4qkBArsoQCQwyQ7iICeKEzqdBa/7rx+w5yQNq1M/RaDBSS2HKqawQkxcR/oI7ZjA2uUgwnxqgPEg4LgtXgGH/MjrMvPy/EqoE0a/1BOUF2sDSyWUZcw6QfoQnBenEtkREyPn0WyfjRcCYi1M0D4pSF73lLUnLGHOBXKCcUCc2yRGs9AGcsCGo+UUmfA+L+stbISctEcCS3YucCsRbO/paiiwQDy7iKJzQgmhAS/ZQYh+ScX8zjWQIZYdytWV28k15NnpbH+T7LCQsD65L+SJ+c/jYAhsZ2Pib37Wn0l2t99+uzqQ8QLLDNdSu9UQLTszgqvvyW5PHh6CrU/mKJAZuzP3QTG4BuuUhGWSfnGNdF3IkYMjTvH8wONjkLuu7y3MVag3bzDnzJO3fxCATpSmb8wRawPJ0V8sORSfTY9+m3NM/ZNFdoyRtBlOK837Il9YZeZYAJsn8222j/xAOFjNjE2PmY2L58PNuswZoRPW2JvvxkaEPJpuqVl0OAOS1P1BpjioYM38rqFgRRJ+iASW7FxACgi+dzcLBYRQJ1eyO+FCAi/ZhUp8jITsUDxiZVoQvLEVhJiYB5Yf1hiHCF09SkM//B5TM8kOq4jH2bzgGp6QQPiwhiAl7smOru9J+8QbGadpDbDbMzc88obFRW4dpEVb9B3y1HVRVmKloQ5BuDbUo0fMFZsDbfutLfONhertH2sH4THfWMgoIa4Z7jsxS4LmEDbxQW/y9skiOwgXgiHIb+Yf6tgyJMJcaZebsROD8x4KQGBYa4QaiBNj/bL+WG/eN7Gwjmz6bEReKx3LF3kkGdi8RhcMAax4U+aRKTYQ8/E9b8FTgHgjQURkN2jQYNfUna1OQ3tTGTt2Qoe+dkZ2CAhKwFE5z3oiEBBEZ+4krhrH3lgfKCXZ4ygEoD2Ene8QOB2ARcDMNk03FiVDaVAi7SZ6gTLhKkOietH9AsmcJkMY7M7cnwMPBNHr/tEeSsfBAvFHdngzwGySnX6Cwg/0F0Wg/5AdwW7iXdqlQXghKfpBn3TfmTcUhf+MheXIIQ3kAmmaRIfljJWKleV3AAI4BeSggvZN60xfjwuOe+QldA3WhhNx05qkD5AKJIEyo/jkiRFgZ810kJ2YEhYtpKD7d7LIDrDOHKax4en6zAnXQFTMM/KhN2Bkn0MyM2xAYWykhLAmpPfgOrK2zKdZj+9YW9M600A22MhYX/MaXZhLcke94IUUyLnX/WVNmHe8G3Nz6Q4iIrtTqXRGdigApj9mO7k/LCqLB/mh4LirmP8USIO4ESdYCDw7D0KFG8RJkgl9SsiCIWS8xQF3lsVnMfV9USAsO4gJIYR8zPtCopAg7aFwxK704vuRHQpHXbN/7NwINKREXI/2CR5zuoyiIrCRvOIJIOBYpGwUBLoZL1YSfWZnB/yE2IltmsrfVcEiYU2w/ki4DmWh0mdInrVDSc02sBK7egUQioOFg4JBtub1FEicdiBDxmcSKnOMAnL4AWmCk0l2bKIkpUMk9Nm8TheToACyhtXmPTzoqjBXHA6Fkg1kHIsYOaXP5rVsEsifN8YLmEcsPnPzobAOyKt+HjwSRDXZoShYclgjxB6YYOIdBFY5fSSmwGkrDxzjuhA7gpiwIlBErjNfjaTBd7yWW8ez+ElsD+Ig7qEtSogSy4H2UFSCv+Z9ISFObNlhIRP9SA0K50d2AGXiyQYsIgSetnEZUT6ID6WGGBBWlNdvHOGSnQY7NP1h50epcSt1jAhAKGwUKCFK5bUQvIU+sx7ModlOKEAuXusRxcUdgni7OrnTVghz7WfB+BXmjjVhPnFle4Nlp+WKzY1cRS9hULxkx9ywGeGBkP7EHIYiPWSZuWEN2ZzxCLqysjiNR27NdjAAOATxu5b+Q9hY/WY/6Bc6gVsdKaKa7DQgPFwZAt1YWpAEwolAs7gUPrMjYV3htmGtsQuFUkQWDAGCVBA62oT0iD9pYBHyvCnuBYrBgpr3RLC5JwuPIkJ+WE7UxSoMFahlR4VIiaEhaH7t0idI1G8c9AvXhntjUXYVENYKhttHuygU1qPX9YRQIELiNcwH/dB9on/0k/lnHVgP1iUcoLgQLvEh+kyBrAm+Y0F3RZYarBkWh55j+kMf9dzp9WBDZO4gDTNGCfiMxaKJ0+wP9b25fp2BQwLmS7dB8cqQH1g/UnUYP/Op5Y/rdaxUW96A2CrvOOREnbmnr6bM8BN9wLVlbiBtLMJw3EninuiLOQayD/ziwBrIDZ4A/dDXsHHhHenk5Uhgyc4FFh6TiBVBMJvTO1xbcoogDOI+PC9LXhIWCoKBsGCqs5v6ASuJAD6WBURAm7hUZg4TbiALi1AjFFgyCAL3xAriaQXeLEycAsUn/kVckcAv/QgVqKVfEBDXkPSMkmEx0i4FCw9XAbfWbxzs9pyWIvwc85vvIvMD12LN8NYRrmGeGKd+a4UGFhRWI0nbxD1xgxgnfWLcEA3xOdaB9TDjnJ2BeeQAhza5PwXrllgasalQa+QFawZR4Crp9aCPyIG5HoQ5CGuwvpCb2T6fmXtCErxiSveHz5C9N1ewM+B+Mx+6DYpXhvzAfHAfrHWeLyXFBPnjetaVF2GaREWfGTubHlYeMT3WAplH9pEdCI4XZkByyKx33KHAZoMMmmMg/owchAJ9Y+1YQ30NsUjkOVRcOxyERXYWFhYWpzos2VlYWEQFLNlZWFhEBSzZWVhYRAUs2VlYWEQFLNlZWFhEBSzZWVhYRAUs2VlYWEQFLNlZWFhEBSzZWVhYRAUs2VlYWEQBRP4ftd9HFPdusAIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
string htmlString = string.Format(@"<html>
                                    <head/>
                                    <body>
                                        <h1>AltChunk HTML with base64 Image</h1>
                                        <p>This is an html document with a base64 image</p>
                                        <img filename='test.jpg' alt='' src='{0}' />
                                        <h1>Results in:</h1>
                                        <p>The linked image cannot be displayed. The file may have been moved,renamed, or deleted. Verify that the link points to the correct file and location.</p>
                                    </body>
                                    </html>", base64Image);

string fileName = @"c:\temp\newdocx.docx";

using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(fileName, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
{
    // Set the content of the document so that Word can open it.
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();

    mainPart.Document = new Document();
    Document document = mainPart.Document;
    Body body = document.AppendChild(new Body());

    // create AltChunk
    string altChunkId = "AltChunkId1";
    AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
        AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Html, 
        altChunkId);

    // add the html to the chunk!
    using (Stream chunkStream = chunk.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        using (StreamWriter stringWriter = new StreamWriter(chunkStream, Encoding.UTF8)) //Encoding.UTF8 is important to remove special characters
        {
            stringWriter.Write(htmlString);
        }
    }

    AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
    altChunk.Id = altChunkId;

    body.AppendChild(altChunk);
    mainPart.Document.Save();
}
```

A screenshot of the problem:
[Problem](http://sdrv.ms/1hwR4NV)

I really would appreciate some help on this case , have been stuck on this for more than 2 day, searched the whole internet I guess :), but nothing I have found could help me out.

Comment: See [html-docx-js](https://github.com/evidenceprime/html-docx-js) how to create MHTML with images for MS Word. Just note, it [does not work on Mac](https://github.com/evidenceprime/html-docx-js/issues/129).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a direct answer to your question, but I do have a work-around if you're stuck.
If you are able to create the html file with a normal image link instead of the embedded binary data, you can use this code to convert it to a .docx with the pictures embedded.

```
// Open Word
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

// Open some html file
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(@"E:\Test2.html");

// Loop through all the pictures
for (int i = 1; i <= doc.InlineShapes.Count; i++)
{
    // Mark it as embedded if it's not
    if (doc.InlineShapes[i].LinkFormat != null && doc.InlineShapes[i].LinkFormat.SavePictureWithDocument == false)
    {
        doc.InlineShapes[i].LinkFormat.SavePictureWithDocument = true;
    }
}

// Save as docx
doc.SaveAs2(@"e:\Test2.docx", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault);

// Close word
wordApp.Quit(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Comment: This worked good for me. However is there a way we can include css amd JS files as well?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should save your HTML text as .html file(with absolute image path), after it with ADODB liberty convert html to mhtml and then whit WordprocessingDocument save it as word document.

below my cod part...

```
                string altChunkId = "myId";
                MainDocumentPart mainDocPart = document.MainDocumentPart;
                var body = mainDocPart.Document.Body;

                string htmlFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid() + ".html");
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(htmlFilePath))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(html);
                    sw.Close();
                }

                string urlHTML = htmlFilePath;
                string urlMHT = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid() + ".mht");

                CDO.Message objMessage = new CDO.Message();
                objMessage.CreateMHTMLBody(urlHTML);

                ADODB.Stream strm = new ADODB.Stream();
                strm.Type = StreamTypeEnum.adTypeText;
                strm.Charset = "US-ASCII";
                strm.Open();
                var dsk = objMessage.DataSource;
                dsk.SaveToObject(strm, "_Stream");
                strm.SaveToFile(urlMHT, SaveOptionsEnum.adSaveCreateOverWrite);
                strm.Close();

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(urlMHT))
                {
                    fs.CopyTo(ms);
                    fs.Close();
                }

                ms.Position = 0;

                AlternativeFormatImportPart formatImportPart =
                   mainDocPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
                      AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Mht, altChunkId);
                formatImportPart.FeedData(ms);
                AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
                altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
                mainDocPart.Document.Body.Append(altChunk);
```